# Monotouch - CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm currently working on a proof of concept app written in monotouch that would record videos. I need to adjust the time of the CMSampleBuffer, I found a code that do just that however it's written in Objective-C. I tried translating the code below, but I can't find any mapping to this function - **CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray**, how are we going to call this function in monotouch? Below is the complete code for adjusting time but in Objective-C:

```
- (CMSampleBufferRef) adjustTime:(CMSampleBufferRef) sample by:(CMTime) offset
{
    CMItemCount count;
    CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray(sample, 0, nil, &count);
    CMSampleTimingInfo* pInfo = malloc(sizeof(CMSampleTimingInfo) * count);
    CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray(sample, count, pInfo, &count);
    for (CMItemCount i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        pInfo[i].decodeTimeStamp = CMTimeSubtract(pInfo[i].decodeTimeStamp, offset);
        pInfo[i].presentationTimeStamp = CMTimeSubtract(pInfo[i].presentationTimeStamp, offset);
    }
    CMSampleBufferRef sout;
    CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(nil, sample, count, pInfo, &sout);
    free(pInfo);
    return sout;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/CoreMedia/CMSampleBuffer.cs the funciton you mention is commented out, but depending what you're doing it may be useful

Comment: Yes I've seen it, Rolf's answer almost work except for the part where we create a CMSampleBuffer passing it a handle. The CMSampleBuffer constructor for that is declared internal.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a vine like video recording functionality, were you can record/pause multiple times. I've successfully duplicated it by recording multiple files and combining the files after (AVMutableComposition) however I can't solve the video flickering problem specially if you do the recording/pause sequence too fast. I figured that there's no need to record it in multiple files, but every time I need to resume, I have to recalculate the time of the CMSampleBuffer so that the video will play continuously.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but I believe it should get you on the right track:

```
[DllImport(Constants.CoreMediaLibrary)]
int CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray (
    IntPtr sbuf,
    int timingArrayEntries,
    CMSampleTimingInfo [] timingArrayOut,
    out int timingArrayEntriesNeededOut
);

[DllImport(Constants.CoreMediaLibrary)]
int CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming (
    IntPtr allocator,
    IntPtr originalSBuf,
    int numSampleTimingEntries,
    CMSampleTimingInfo []sampleTimingArray,
    out IntPtr sBufCopyOut
);

CMSampleBuffer AdjustTime (CMSampleBuffer sample, CMTime offset)
{
    int count;
    CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray (sample.Handle, 0, null, out count);
    CMSampleTimingInfo [] pInfo = new CMSampleTimingInfo [count];
    CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray (sample.Handle, count, pInfo, out count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        pInfo [i].DecodeTimeStamp = CMTime.Subtract (pInfo [i].DecodeTimeStamp, offset);
        pInfo [i].PresentationTimeStamp = CMTime.Subtract (pInfo [i].PresentationTimeStamp, offset);
    }
    IntPtr sout;
    CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithTiming (IntPtr.Zero, sample, count, pInfo, out sout);
    // Unfortunately the constructor we need is internal, but that can be fixed
    // for a future version of Xamarin.iOS.
    return (CMSampleBuffer) typeof (CMSampleBuffer).GetConstructor (BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type [] { typeof (IntPtr), typeof (bool) }, null).Invoke (new object [] { sout, true });
}
```

**Update**

I have implemented some of the required API in Xamarin.iOS now, so in future versions you'll be able to do this:

```
CMSampleBuffer AdjustTime (CMSampleBuffer sample, CMTime offset)
{
    var info = sample.GetSampleTimingInfo ();
    for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++) {
        info [i].DecodeTimeStamp = CMTime.Subtract (info [i].DecodeTimeStamp, offset);
        info [i].PresentationTimeStamp = CMTime.Subtract (info [i].PresentationTimeStamp, offset);
    }
    return CMSampleBuffer.CreateWithNewTiming (sample, info)
}
```

Comment: hi Rolf,

I don't think we can invoke this constructor -> CMSampleBuffer(IntPtr handle), It's declared with an accessibility of internal. When I tried compiling the code, the compiler complains that the constructor is inacccessible due to it's protection level. Is there another way we can create a CMSampleBuffer from a handle?

Comment: I've updated the sample to use reflection to get and invoke the internal constructor. Let me know if this actually works and I'll make the constructor public (or provide an API for this whole thing).

Comment: hi Rolf, still didn't work CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithTiming returned a status == 0, however the call GetConstructor(..).Invoke throws a null pointer exception.